# Настройка VDS на максимальную производительность

Tags: php, mysql, vds

Добрый день.
В администрировании полный ноль и поэтому прошу совета, что из перечисленного ниже рекомендуется включить для максимально быстрой работы PHP + MySQL на сервере? От версии PHP будет зависеть скорость?
В основном, запросы к MySQL не сложные, вида `SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE a=b,` но частота запросов большая.
Спасибо!

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не используете код, который закодирован с помощью Zend Encoder и Zend SafeGuard Suite или IonCube - то выключайте Optimizer и IonCube Loader.

ZendOPCache - в php5.5 включен по умолчанию. 
Если ваш код написан под младшие версии php включайте только APC.

Xdebug - это для отладки - этим надо дома заниматься.